# Checking $\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}} dx}$ for convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

> Given $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}  dx}$, prove that it converges.

So of course, I said:

> We have to calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to \infty} {\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}  dx}}$. And in order to do that we have to calculate the integral $\displaystyle \int {\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}  dx}$.

I got stuck calculating this integral, if anyone can give me a direction with this question I'll appreciate it!

Comment: Try using a comparision test with an appropriate $p$-series. (Split the integral up first.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the inequalities

$$
0\le\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}\le
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}\le
\frac{1}{x^{7/3}}
$$

so your integral will converge if

$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{7/3}}\,dx
$$

does. The change of the integration bounds is irrelevant, because
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7 + 1}}\,dx
$$
poses no problem.

Now

$$
\int_1^{a}\frac{1}{x^{7/3}}\,dx=\left[-\frac{3}{4}x^{-4/3}\right]_1^a
=-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4}a^{-4/3}
$$

and

$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}a^{-4/3}=0
$$

It's quite improbable that you can find the "exact" value of the proposed integral, but the question was only to check for convergence.

Comment: So, the limit for the second integral when $a \to \infty$ is $< 1$ thus it converges, and thus our original integral converges?

Comment: @TheNotMe It's not relevant that the limit is less than $1$, it suffices it exists. Think to it with areas: the area delimited by the function $x\mapsto x^{-4/3}$ is finite and your function delimits a smaller area. It's also important to note that the function is non negative; I added it to the set of inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

You're not meant to *calculate* the integral, you're meant to *check it converges*.

Since the integrand is finite and continuous everywhere, the only possible thing which can go wrong is that it does not converge at infinity.

The behaviour at large $x$ is asymptotically $\sin^2 x^{-7/3}$. Now this is bounded by $x^{-7/3}$ which has a finite integral $\propto x^{-4/3}$ which converges at infinity; the result is that the integral does indeed converge.